# {reversing and indexing together} in pandas. Not getting expected output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
series = pd.Series(['A', 'B', 'C','D'], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

I want:

```
c    C
b    B
a    A
dtype: object
```

I tried:

```
series['a':'c':-1]
```

but I'm getting:

```
Series([], dtype: object)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
series['c':'a':-1]
```

output:

```
c    C
b    B
a    A
dtype: object
```

Comment: Or `series[::-1]` in this particular case

Comment: I've mentioned in the question I don't want 
`d     D`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `series.loc` to obtain the same result.

```
series.loc['c'::-1]

c    C
b    B
a    A
dtype: object
```